# Using parameter instead of a model definiton

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Component is a model,and `Storage` is one of its definitons.Is there a way to use a parameter instead of `Storage`?

```
public IActionResult Filtered(string parameter)

        {
            
            return View(viewModel.Where(x => x.Component.Storage != "").ToList());

        }
```

Comment: Where is the parameter? Which Parameter?

Comment: a value that I will post from a select on my view. I am planning to use that as a parameter for Filtered function

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that parameter is of type `string`. This is just a sample code. You can customize it to your needs.

```
var res = from m in viewModel // I don't know what is inside this viewModel
          where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)
          select m;
  return View(res);
```

Comment: I guess this is checking if parameter is empty or null  then selects everything inside the  viewModel because I always have a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

To get the parameter from the url add it to the function

```
public IActionResult Filtered(string propertyName)
{
    var prop = typeof(Component).GetProperty(propertyName)
    return View(viewModel.Where(x => !Equals(prop.GetValue(x.Component), "")).ToList());
}
```

Comment: but I don't want to use Storage, it is one of the parameters

Comment: @E__ something like this?

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @E__ what didn't work? Exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get value by parameter like this

```
var component = new Component { Storage = "A1" };
var valueOfName = component["Name"];
Console.WriteLine(valueOfName);

public partial class Component
{
    public string Storage { get; set; }

    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var type = GetType();
            var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (property == null) throw new Exception("Class donesn't have this property");
            var value = property.GetValue(this, null);
            return value;
        }
        private set{};
    }
}
```

If you can modify the `class` you don't need the `partial` key word on `Component class`

Comment: Do I need to create Component objects for every posssible parameter?

Comment: I can't get you. Could you try then feedback what's issue you get

Comment: for the part :``var component = new Component { Storage = "A1" };`` where should i add the other values inside the Component class?

Comment: Value or property? If you need others property add it in the class. If you are talking about set value for property just set where you want

Comment: sorry,parameter. Thanks.

Comment: If you have the other parameter call ```Age``` just use ```component["Age"];``` but before this you should add a property ```Age``` in component class